# Add missing values with duplicate values in CSV using VB6

Tags: csv, vb6, adodb

I have a CSV file as shown in below image. Which contains the columns as *Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Close and Volume* respectively.

[image: Sample image of CSV]

In that, Time column should have sequential difference such as *1 min, 3 mins, 5 mins, 30 mins, etc.,* Here below, my sample CSV file has 1 min data difference with inconsistent time interval.

**I want to insert values for missing time with value of last valid time value up to next valid time value.**

**For ex:**
**Actual File:** 
1/2/2014 14:09 has 9.68, 9.76, 9.68, 9.75 and 800 
1/2/2014 14:10 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 15:31 has 9.67, 9.7, 9.65, 9.66 and 400 
1/2/2014 15:32 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
1/2/2014 16:00 has 9.74, 9.74, 9.74, 9.74 and 512

**Expected result:** 
1/2/2014 14:09 has 9.68, 9.76, 9.68, 9.75 and 800 
1/2/2014 14:10 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 14:11 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 14:12 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 14:13 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 14:14 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 14:15 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
**.....** 
**.....** 
**.....** 
**.....** 
1/2/2014 15:30 has 9.72, 9.73, 9.72, 9.73 and 300 
1/2/2014 15:31 has 9.67, 9.7, 9.65, 9.66 and 400 
1/2/2014 15:32 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
1/2/2014 15:33 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
1/2/2014 15:34 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
1/2/2014 15:35 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
**.....** 
**.....** 
**.....** 
**.....** 
1/2/2014 15:59 has 9.75, 9.75, 9.75, 9.75 and 400 
1/2/2014 16:00 has 9.74, 9.74, 9.74, 9.74 and 512

***Note:*** I want to be implemented without using Excel application object. My client requirement is not allow to use Excel object.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: If it is a CSV file why would you have to use Excel anyway? Why not simple read the file into a Data Table object and then manipulate the data anyway you see fit.